# How can i get the serial from subtable

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two tables one is serial and main. I show the two table format below. I would like to get the exact output below. I am new for this field. Kindly help me to do this.

Serial

```
FLD_ID  FLD_SERIAL  FLD_TYPE
1   1234-34563-2323-2345    MONITOR
2   1234-34563-2323-2346    KEYBOARD
3   1234-34563-2323-2347    MONITOR
4   1234-34563-2323-2348    MONITOR
5   1234-34563-2323-2349    MONITOR
6   1234-34563-2323-2350    MONITOR
7   1234-34563-2323-2351    KEYBOARD
8   1234-34563-2323-2352    CPU
9   1234-34563-2323-2353    CPU
10  1234-34563-2323-2354    CPU
```

Main

```
FLD_ID  FLD_CPU FLD_MONITOR FLD_KEYBOARD
1           8   1           7
2           9   4   
3          10               2
```

Expected Output

```
FLD_ID  FLD_CPU                 FLD_MONITOR         FLD_KEYBOARD
1   1234-34563-2323-2352    1234-34563-2323-2345    1234-34563-2323-2351
2   1234-34563-2323-2353    1234-34563-2323-2348    
3   1234-34563-2323-2354                        1234-34563-2323-2346
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work for you:

```
SELECT 
  `FLD_ID`,
  IFNULL((SELECT `FLD_SERIAL` FROM `Serial` WHERE `FLD_ID` = `FLD_CPU`),'') AS `FLD_CPU`,
  IFNULL((SELECT `FLD_SERIAL` FROM `Serial` WHERE `FLD_ID` = `FLD_MONITOR`),'') AS `FLD_MONITOR`,
  IFNULL((SELECT `FLD_SERIAL` FROM `Serial` WHERE `FLD_ID` = `FLD_KEYBOARD`),'') AS `FLD_KEYBOARD`
FROM
  `Main`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select FLD_ID, cpu.FLD_SERIAL as FLD_CPU, mon.FLD_SERIAL as FLD_MONITOR, kbd.FLD_SERIAL as FLD_KEYBOARD
from main
left join Serial as cpu on FLD_CPU = cpu.FLD_ID
left join Serial as mon on FLD_MONITOR = mon.FLD_ID
left join Serial as kbd on FLD_KEYBOARD = kbd.FLD_ID
```

(untested)

Edit: 
To make sure of the database consistency you should also check if all the entries marked "CPU" correspond to cpu fields in the main table, and likewise for monitors and keyboards.